# Is local port forwarding to untrusted remote safe?

Tags: ssh, security

Suppose I `ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 user@ip_address` into a untrusted machine and do nothing else (not running `sudo`, not running any commands, just leaving the connection open).

Could the `-L 5901:localhost:5901` be dangerous under a default configuration?

Comment: I assume this is for VNC? I guess as long as VNC is secured it's no different than if you port forwarded 5901 on your router

Comment: @JaromandaX since it is an untrusted remote, there is no guarantee it is VNC on port 5901. I am asking because there are analogies of reverse tunnelling being a "tube" and I want to know if it's possible for the remote to "push trash backwards".

Comment: so, you don't know what's listening on port 5901 on your own machine. So why are you reverse tunneling to it? Oh, wait, `-L` is not **reverse tunneling** - you're forwarding a port to the untrusted machine, shouldn't be an issue at all